# Enhance a php regular expression to not include values from specific html attributes

Tags: php, regex

I have the following php regular expression that I use to select/extract plain text emails from html pages:

```
/(^[^<\s? input ].*)(?<=[^\w\d\+_.:-])(?:[-!#$%&*+\/=?^_`.{|}~\w\x80-\xFF]+|".*?")\@(?:[-a-z0-9\x80-\xFF]+(?:\.[-a-z0-9\x80-\xFF]+)*\.[a-z]+|\[[\d.a-fA-F:]+\])(?!(?>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/?a\b)[^<]*)*)<\/a>)/i
```

The problem is that it selects also emails from html attributes like value="somemail@something.com" or placeholder='somemail@someserver.org' which I don't want that. So I try to modify/enhance it, in order to exclude the attributes.

The following sentence is ok:

```
<p>hello my name is  etsefefsda@gmail.com and thats it.</p>
```

The following four should be excluded from the selection (notice the single, double and no quotes after the equal sign):

```
<p data-email='an_email@here.com'
<input value="someone@yahoo.co.uk"
<input placeholder="someone@preosmail.com"
<input placeholder=someone@servermail.com
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a valid email never comes after an unclosed `<`, try a variation of the following:

`<[^>]+@(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|@`

## Explanation

- `<[^>]+` Finds a `<` followed by no `>`
- `@` Finds an `@`
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` YE SHALL NOT PASS. With "ye" meaning an email within an unclosed tag.
- `|@` Find any correct email addresses.

  - You should replace the `@` sign with your regex to find emails. I have it as a placeholder here.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot Laurel.